# Why is an entity not being fetched from NDB's in-context cache?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an entity that is used to store some global app settings. These settings can be edited via an admin HTML page, but very rarely change. I have only one instance of this entity (a singleton of sorts) and always refer to this instance when I need access to the settings.

Here's what it boils down to:

```py
class Settings(ndb.Model):
    SINGLETON_DATASTORE_KEY = 'SINGLETON'

    @classmethod
    def singleton(cls):
        return cls.get_or_insert(cls.SINGLETON_DATASTORE_KEY)

    foo = ndb.IntegerProperty(
        default =  100,
        verbose_name = "Some setting called 'foo'",
        indexed = False)

@ndb.tasklet
def foo():
    # Even though settings has already been fetched from memcache and
    # should be available in NDB's in-context cache, the following call
    # fetches it from memcache anyways. Why?
    settings = Settings.singleton()

class SomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @ndb.toplevel
    def get(self):
        settings = Settings.singleton()
        # Do some stuff
        yield foo()
        self.response.write("The 'foo' setting value is %d" % settings.foo)
```

I was under the assumption that calling `Settings.singleton()` more than once per request handler would be pretty fast, as the first call would most probably retrieve the `Settings` entity from memcache (since the entity is seldom updated) and all subsequent calls within the same request handler would retrieve it from NDB's in-context cache. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#incontext):

> The in-context cache persists only for the duration of a single incoming HTTP request and is "visible" only to the code that handles that request. It's fast; this cache lives in memory.

However, AppStat is showing that my `Settings` entity is being retrieved from memcache multiple times within the same request handler. I know this by looking at a request handler's detailed page in AppStat, expanding the call trace of each call to `memcache.Get` and looking at the memcahe key that is being reteived.

I am using a lot of tasklets in my request handlers, and I call `Settings.singleton()` from within the tasklets that need access to the settings. Could this be the reason why the Settings entity is being fetched from memcache again instead of from the in-context cache? If so, what are the exact rules that govern if/when an entity can be fetched from the in-context cache or not? I have not been able to find this information in the NDB documentation.

---

**Update 2013/02/15:** I am unable to reproduce this in a dummy test application. Test code is:

```py
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    prop_a = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

def use_foo():
    foo = Foo.get_or_insert('singleton')
    logging.info("Function using foo: %r", foo.prop_a)

@ndb.tasklet
def use_foo_tasklet():
    foo = Foo.get_or_insert('singleton')
    logging.info("Function using foo: %r", foo.prop_a)

@ndb.tasklet
def use_foo_async_tasklet():
    foo = yield Foo.get_or_insert_async('singleton')
    logging.info("Function using foo: %r", foo.prop_a)

class FuncGetOrInsertHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            logging.info("Iteration %d", i)
            use_foo()

class TaskletGetOrInsertHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @ndb.toplevel
    def get(self):
        logging.info("Toplevel")
        use_foo()
        for i in xrange(10):
            logging.info("Iteration %d", i)
            use_foo_tasklet()

class AsyncTaskletGetOrInsertHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @ndb.toplevel
    def get(self):
        logging.info("Toplevel")
        use_foo()
        for i in xrange(10):
            logging.info("Iteration %d", i)
            use_foo_async_tasklet()
```

Before running any of the test handlers, I make sure that the `Foo` entity with keyname *singleton* exists.

Contrary to what I am seeing in my production app, all of these request handlers show a single call to `memcache.Get` in Appstats.

---

**Update 2013/02/21:** I am finally able to reproduce this in a dummy test application. Test code is:

```py
class ToplevelAsyncTaskletGetOrInsertHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @ndb.toplevel
    def get(self):
        logging.info("Toplevel 1")
        use_foo()
        self._toplevel2()

    @ndb.toplevel
    def _toplevel2(self):
        logging.info("Toplevel 2")
        use_foo()
        for i in xrange(10):
            logging.info("Iteration %d", i)
            use_foo_async_tasklet()
```

This handler does show 2 calls to `memcache.Get` in Appstats, just like my production code.

Indeed, in my production request handler codepath, I have a `toplevel` called by another `toplevel`. It seems like a `toplevel` creates a new ndb context.

Changing the nested `toplevel` to a `synctasklet` fixes the problem.

Comment: Is there a difference between get and get_or_insert?

Comment: Nope. Using using `get_by_id()` instead of `get_or_insert()` still yields to multiple fetches from memcache within a single request handler.

Comment: `get_or_insert()` runs in a transaction, which supposedly bypasses memcache. So this doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this in an isolated test app. Calling `get_or_insert()` multiple times from sub-functions and tasklets end up with a single `memcache.Get` call in AppStats. So there has to be something else in my production code that leads to this singleton being fetched from memcache more than once within a single handler. Investigating...

Comment: How exactly are you testing this? The memcache only gets populated the first time you *get* the data (not when you put it) so to test whether you are seeing a cached access you need to write it, read it, and read it again (in a separate request). The second read should use memcache.

Comment: I'm testing with an entity that is never updated, because this is what is happening in my production code. So I create the entity before running my tests, then all my tests simply call `get_or_insert('singleton')` multiple times from within the same handler, yielding to tasklets which also read the singleton. In my tests, only 1 memcache read is done. In my real app, I see many memcache reads for that singleton entity (which is never updated). Are there any rules governing the propagation of the context that could cause this (where my tasklets would not share the main context)?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I am using in my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like a toplevel creates a new ndb context.

Exactly, each handler with a `toplevel` decorator have its own context and therefore a separate cache. You can take a look to the code for `toplevel` in the link below, in the function documentation states that `toplevel` is "A sync tasklet that sets a fresh default Context".

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py#1033